# How can I get Angular to show intellisense parameters in VSCode on typed objects in the HTML template?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

In my class file of my Angular component, I have arrays of objects that are typed.

The autocomplete works in that file.

**interfaces.ts**

```
export interface IOriginalPlace {
  idCode: string,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  tags: string,
  latitude: number
  longitude: number
}

export interface IPlace extends IOriginalPlace{
    googleMapUrl: string;
}
```

**prague.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as model from '../../dataLayer/model';
import { IPlace } from '../../dataLayer/interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prague',
  templateUrl: './prague.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prague.component.scss']
})
export class PragueComponent {
  places: IPlace[] = model.getPraguePlaces();

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

How do I get autocomplete to work in the HTML template file?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else with this issue, what finally solved it for me was to simply **uninstall and install** the VSCode extension [Angular Language Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template).

[image]

After that, auto-completion of TypeScript variables works well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. That solved my problem as well. VSCode is weird sometimes.